# 3D graphing on a 3-D plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, 3d

How would this function look hand drawn using the x,y,z axis: $$||x^2+y^2||$$

Comment: You've drawn $f(x,y)=|x|$.  The "crease" needs to be along the line $y=-x$, but you have it at $x=0$.

Comment: It might; you should label your axes.  The function, like most 3d functions, is hard to draw.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the range of the function, then draw level curves:

f(x,y) = |x+y| = 0

f(x,y) = |x+y| = 1

f(x,y) = |x+y| = 2

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can verify this with 2-D intersections.

Imagine (yet unknown) 3-D object intersected by a plane $z=w$. We know the object equation is $z=f(x,y)\equiv |x+y|$ and the plane is parallel to the $xy$ plane for every $w$.

Now it's all about computing and imagining those intersections for different values of $w$ i.e. for different $z$ coordinates.

---

For $w<0$ we have:

$$w=|x+y|<0$$

with no solutions; none of the $z=w$ planes intersects with the object in this case.

---

For $w=0$ the equation is:

$$0=|x+y|$$
$$0=x+y$$
$$y=-x$$

This is the "crease" mentioned in *vadim123*'s comment. At this point we already know your drawing is wrong.

---

For $w=1$:

$$1=|x+y|$$
$$(x+y=-1) \vee (x+y=1)$$
$$(y=-x-1) \vee (y=-x+1)$$

So there are two parallel lines at $z=1$.

---

For $w=2$ we have…

…

The two lines are more distant than those previous ones.

---

For $w=3$…

And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the response - so would this work as a good sketch? http://imgur.com/a/ODW2z

Comment: here are the axis' labeled: http://imgur.com/a/SgpQo

Comment: @asdfghjkl It may look almost like this when you restrict to $(x\in<x_1;x_2>) \wedge (y\in<y_1;y_2>)$. Due to ambiguity of this (and any) flat picture I cannot tell for sure if you got the concept right in 3D. Certainly there is one error though: the "crease" should go through the origin, in your picture it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, I used a 3-D tool and got this:http://imgur.com/a/TstxH